# using org.mpris.mediaplayer2.player PlaybackStatus property in python

Tags: python, string, media-player, dbus

The [Specification page](http://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/Player_Interface.html#summary) for this particular interface says:

```
PlaybackStatus — s (Playback_Status)
.
.
.
May be "Playing", "Paused" or "Stopped".
```

But when i read it like this:

```
print "Song %s" % iPlayer.PlaybackStatus
```

or

```
if iPlayer.PlaybackStatus == "Playing":
    print "Song playing"
```

It shows a very strange output like `<dbus.proxies._ProxyMethod instance at 0x255f248>`

How can I access the String value of this variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call the `Get` method to get the property. The method returns a string. I did the following to get playback status of VLC player:

```
import dbus

bus = dbus.SessionBus()
vlc_media_player_obj = bus.get_object("org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc", "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2")
props_iface = dbus.Interface(vlc_media_player_obj, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
pb_stat = props_iface.Get('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player', 'PlaybackStatus')
```

In my case (and hopefully in yours), the object also had a `org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties` interface, which has the `Get` method, which you can call as above.