# Python+D-Bus+BlueZ 5: can't read property of object?

Tags: python, linux, dbus, bluez

This is on Gentoo Linux.

I'm trying to get BlueZ 5 to tell me whether my bluetooth headset is connected or not.

I have read and re-read the D-Bus « documentation » on freedesktop.org but it seems badly outdated (or incomplete, or both). I have also tried to understand the meager information on bluez.org, but without much luck.

I have tried the following:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Apr 26 2014, 11:38:54) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dbus
>>> bus = dbus.SystemBus()
>>> obj = bus.get_object( "org.bluez", '/org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_18_91_D0_7A_24' )
>>> iface = dbus.Interface( obj, "org.bluez.Device1" )
>>> print iface.Connected
<dbus.proxies._DeferredMethod instance at 0x236e2d8>
```

I thought Connected was a property of the device, but it's a _DeferredMethod? How can I get the value of this property then?

Comment: Seems like you need to call it: `print iface.Connected()`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to read properties from a Bluetooth device via D-Bus API:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import dbus

bus = dbus.SystemBus()
adapter_object = bus.get_object('org.bluez', '/org/bluez/hci0')
adapter = dbus.Interface(adapter_object, 'org.bluez.Adapter1')

device_object = bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_FC_52_6E_8E_87_06")
device = dbus.Interface(device_object, "org.bluez.Device1")

device_properties = dbus.Interface(device, "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")
print(device_properties.Get("org.bluez.Device1", "Name"))
print(device_properties.Get("org.bluez.Device1", "Connected"))
```

Answer (score 2):

DBus properties are accessed indirectly via dbus method calls to the Get method. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324841/using-org-mpris-mediaplayer2-player-playbackstatus-property-in-python)